# How to implement a boolean OR update instraction?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgresql...
I need to implenet a function that merge two rows in the table.

assume that I already have the id of the two rows and it's ok to merge them.

**Example:**

```
id quantity isOK
5     20     FALSE
5     10     FALSE
6     30     TRUE
6     35     FALSE
```

after calling on id 5 the table will **CHANGED** to:

```
id quantity isOK
5     30     FALSE
6     30     TRUE
6     35     FALSE
```

If calling **again** on id 6 table will **CHANGED**  to:

```
id quantity isOK
5     30     FALSE
6     65     TRUE
```

so basicly each call takes two rows and make from them one **combined** row.

What I have so far is simply add the quantity on the 1st to the 2nd and delete the 1st.

I need to modify my function so that there will be an `BOOLEAN OR` operation on the `isOK` field. 
is there a way to do that without using `IF`?
This is how I did it with `IF`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func()
  RETURNS integer AS

   ......

    select isOK into x from A where firstrecord

    if x then
        update A set isOK=x where secondrecord
    end if;

   update quantity

   delete the first record

return 0;                       
end;                
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: how come two rows with `id=6` in this(`after calling on id 5 the table will be:`) condition ?

Comment: GROUP BY, and aggregate function SUM.

Comment: @wingedpanther its calling for the second time in a row.. see edit

Comment: @jarlh how does group by helps here? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @java Can you show your final expected output ?

Comment: @wingedpanther see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXISTS()` yields a boolean, which can be used in the result

```
=-- The table
CREATE TABLE t_test(id INTEGER,value INTEGER, fld Boolean);
-- The data
INSERT INTO t_test (id, value, fld)
VALUES (1, 23, 'TRUE'), (1, 22, 'FALSE'), (2, 2, 'FALSE'), (2, 23, 'FALSE');

-- The query
SELECT t.id
        , SUM(t.value)
        , EXISTS( SELECT 1
        FROM t_test x
        WHERE x.id  = t.id AND x.fld = True
        ) AS fld
FROM t_test t
GROUP by t.id
        ;
```

---

Another way is to cast to-and-fro to integer (booleans are unordered, so you cannot use max on them)

```
SELECT t.id
        , sum(t.value) AS value
        , MAX( t.fld::integer )::boolean AS fld
FROM t_test t
GROUP by t.id
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

First take the desired id as parameter:

```
create function myfunc(selectedid integer) returns integer as
```

Declare two local variables:

```
declare mergedquantity integer; mergedisOK boolean;
```

Then merge the records:

```
select sum(quantity), case when sum(isOK) > 0 then true else false end
into mergedquantity, mergedisOK
from a
where id = selectedid;
```

Now you can delete old ones and insert a merged record:

```
delete from a where id = selectedid;
insert into a values(selectedid, mergedquantity, mergedisOK);
```

Comment: Using case and using IF is the same thing.... I was wondring if it can be don'e without any of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by using case function and the using sum

```
create table t_test1(id number,value number, fld Varchar2(10));
Insert into T_TEST1
   (ID, VALUE, FLD)
Values
   (1, 23, 'TRUE');
Insert into T_TEST1
   (ID, VALUE, FLD)
Values
   (1, 22, 'FALSE');
Insert into T_TEST1
   (ID, VALUE, FLD)
Values
   (2, 2, 'FALSE');
Insert into T_TEST1
   (ID, VALUE, FLD)
Values
   (2, 23, 'FALSE');



select id,sum(value),case(case sum(case fld
            when 'FALSE' then 0
            else 1
            end
)
        when 0 then 0
        else 1 
       end)
       when 1 then 'TRUE'
       else 'FALSE'
       end
      from t_test1
group by id;
```